# View association object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi i have a table that is called contractors this is acting as the users model for logging into the system. I have a second table called employees. I have created the relationship between the two tables. contractors has_many employees and employees belong_to contractor.

The employee table has a field for contractor id as a foreign key.

When the contractor logs into how can i set the view to only show him the employees that belong to him

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your authentication works, but sou should have something like `current_user` helper which retrieves the currently logged in user from session. Devise gem, for example, creates it automatically.

```
@employees = current_user.employees
```